# Force JNI Get<type>ArrayElements to return a pointer

Tags: java, java-native-interface

in the JNI method Get(Type)ArrayElements [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314), it is written

> "*the returned array may be a copy of the Java array*".

Therefore, this method returns either a pointer or a copy of the Java array. I made a simple test in my code, and indeed, this method returns a copy.
Except that I wish to use native methods to speed-up huge images processing, therefore process BIG arrays. But if using a native code means duplicate my arrays, the performances will deeply suffer and I can lack in RAM.

So my question is: is there a way to force this method to return a pointer instead of a copy?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot force non-copy. You can *encourage* in-place behavior by using instead `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` with the corresponding Release. Read documentation carefully because use of this function imposes significant limitations to what you can do, in addition to usual JNI limitations.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help. I tried this function and indeed, this method returns a pointer instead of a copy.

Comment: I guess that's the method mentioned into the Get(Type)ArrayElements method note: "New functions introduced in JDK/JRE 1.3 allow native code to obtain a direct pointer to array elements even if the VM does not support pinning."
As I am going to make operations only on the arrays, I don't face the issues mentioned into the doc.